# How do I write a generic Save() method that handles single objects and collections?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, generics, save

I have two generic save methods in a repository class:

```
public void Save<T>(T entity)
{
    _session.Save(entity);
}

public void Save<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
    foreach (var item in entities)
    {
        _session.Save(item);
    }
}
```

However, when I use `Save(collection)` (which infers the type automatically), it recognizes it as a `T` rather than `IEnumerable<T>` and tries to save it using the first method.

How do I write this save method(s) so that it can handle either case, without me having to explicitly provide the type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the type parameter at the class level on your repository instead of at the method level, this way the overload will not be ambiguous.

```
class Repo<T>
{
    public void Save(T entity)
    {
        _session.Save(entity);
    }

    public void Save(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        foreach (var item in entities)
        {
            _session.Save(item);
        }
    }
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
var repo = new Repo<Person>();

var p = new Person();
repo.Save(p);

var ps = new Person[] { p };
repo.Save(ps);
```

Comment: What do I do if I want to keep the repository typeless? I'd like to be able to instantiate the repository and query for any entity by passing a type to `Get()`. This saves me the trouble of instantiating multiple copies of the same repository where the only difference between them is the type.

Comment: To clarify, I'd like to be able to do this: `var repo = new Repository(); repo.Get<Ark>(); repo.Get<Animal>(); repo.Get<Food>();` instead of: `var repo1 = new Repository<Ark>(); var repo2 = new Repository<Animal>(); var repo3 = new Repository<Food>();`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on type inference for this specific case. `<T>(T)` will satisfy any type, so the inference won't continue searching to find more specific constraints which still meet the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Whjy bother with overloaded methods?, isn't better to do it like:

```
public void Save<T>(T entity)
{
    if (T is IEnumerable)
    {
         foreach (var item in entity)
              _session..Save(item);
    } else  {
        _session.Save(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't follow SRP. The fact that the name of the parameter doesn't accurately describe the value it could contain is a big code smell warning.

Comment: One solution that seems to work elegantly enough is to just split it into two separate methods with different signatures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this also:

```
    public void Save<T>(T entity)
    {
        if (typeof(T).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable)))
        {
            SaveEnumerable(entity as IEnumerable);
        }
        else
        {
            _session.Save(entity);
        }
    }

    public void SaveEnumerable(IEnumerable entities)
    {
        foreach (var item in entities)
        {
            _session.Save(item);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!!