# Create Generic Save() Method that works with Generice Class

Tags: c#, generics

I Have an external class, lets say XMLSerializer which its signature is `XMLSerializer<T>....`
that class should get the type and then save it into file.
I have another class "GeometricsObject" and 6 other classes which are derived from that class. those classes need to be saved. I was trying for 3 hours to create a generic method

```
public void Save<T>(T obj,string fileName){
 XMLSerializer<T>.save(obj,fileName);
}
```

the problem is when I tried to save Rectangle which is `public class Rectangle :GeometricsObject`
the xmlserializer expected `<T>` which was GeometricsObject but the obj was recognized as Rectangle. then I got an exception.

I was trying to use a shared interface and save those objects who implement this interface but the problem remained.

I tried those [Creating a Generic Save() Method for Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395993/creating-a-generic-save-method-for-models)

[How do I write a generic Save() method that handles single objects and collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931810/how-do-i-write-a-generic-save-method-that-handles-single-objects-and-collectio)

I tried

```
public void Save<T>(T obj,string fileName) where T:(here i tried interface and base class){
 XMLSerializer<T>.save(obj,fileName);
}
```

did not work.

the only thing that worked was not using generics but using a virtual Save(..) within GeometricsObject class and then each derived class overriden that function and insert its own type. but this solution a bit lame in my opinion. there must be a way of single method.

thanks!

Comment: You're looking way too narrow. That you use the `Save()` method in a generic way is hardly relevant. Keywords are inheritance and `XmlInclude`, which I'm sure you'd have found if you searched for the actual exception you get.

Comment: How are you calling the Save method on the rectangle object?

Comment: codeCaster, I did not understand your answer at all. the exception occurred because the XMLSerializer detected T as base class however the object to save was Rectangle 

James Buck, I tried a static method. there must be a way of using a single method instead Save() within each class

Comment: You need to show and research the actual exception. The serializer sees the actual type of `T`, but it doesn't _know_ about that type. You can fix the latter by using the proper attibutes.

Comment: you gave my question -1 becuase you dont know how to answer it?
I'm telling you I know why the exception was thrown there is a mismatch between the object Im trying to save and the acctual type the xml class detects

Comment: @Tamir1989 When calling the Save method do you pass in the type as `Save<GeometricObject>(...)`?

Comment: nope, as i mentioned above I only call save(obj,filename)

Comment: Can you post some code displaying some examples of how you intend to call Save?  Also, please post the exception that you received.  Also, was it an exception or a compiler error?

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend you to move the (de)serialization logic, however tiny it is, out from `GeometricObject` into, say, `GeometricObjectSerializer`, which would then be able to have

```
public void Serialize<T>(...)
    where T : GeometricObject
```

Comment: the problem with that solution is when I tried to save a Rectangle which is derived from GeometricObject class  the XMLSerializer detected T as GeometricObject  however the object itself was type of Rectangle and then an exception was thrown.

Comment: How did the XmlSerializer class detect T as GeometricObject?  Did you provide GeometricObject as a type argument for T somewhere?